# How to customize open/save file dialogs?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, dialog

I have seen some programs use custom open/save file dialogs in that manner they add some extra buttons there.

How can I do this?

Note that I want to use the basic open/save dialogs, so I dont have to re-create them, thus remain the buttons in the OS language. I only want to add some extra buttons there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Update:* As David Heffernan points out below, this answer applies to Windows platforms before Vista. From Vista onwards, you should use the
>   [IFileDialogCustomize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775912.aspx) COM interface instead.

Basically, you have to set the `OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE` flag in the [OPENFILENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) structure you're passing to `GetOpenFileName()`/`GetSaveFileName()`. This allows you to specify a custom dialog template in the `lpTemplateName` member of the same structure. This template will be used to build the dialog box. See [Explorer-Style Custom Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960.aspx#_win32_Explorer_Style_Custom_Templates) for all the details.

Note that if you add your own controls to the dialog box (buttons in your case), you should 
also set the `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` flag and specify a callback function in the `lpfnHook` member of the `OPENFILENAME` structure, so you can handle the messages sent by these controls. See [Explorer-Style Hook Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960.aspx#_win32_Explorer_Style_Hook_Procedures) for more information.

Comment: That was the correct answer 5 years ago, but since Vista it has been more complex. Nowadays you need to use [`IFileDialogCustomize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775912.aspx). If you use templates you end up with the revolting legacy dialogs.

Comment: @David, very interesting, I was not aware dialog box customization was changed in Vista. I updated my answer accordingly, thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Unfortunately most of us still need to support clients using both XP and Vista/7. Which means that we have to write the template code **and** the `IFileDialogCustomize` code, and switch behaviour at runtime.

Comment: @David Heffernan, does the "only XP compatible" template thing work on vista too...? i really dont care if it looks ugly or anything.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you
[Customizing common dialog controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)